# How can I make this VB.NET code more efficient and faster?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, performance

I've been trying to make this code faster and more efficient for a few days now, but it still doesn't seem as efficient as it could be.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    Dim l As New List(Of ULong)(CType(My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0), ULong))
    For i As ULong = 1 To l.Capacity
        ' ONE LINE IF STMT: If l.Capacity And 1 <> 0 Then If i And 1 = 0 Then l.Add((i * i) - 1) Else l.Add((i * i) + 1) Else If i And 1 = 0 Then l.Add((i * i) + 1) Else l.Add((i * i) - 1)
        If l.Capacity And 1 <> 0 Then
            If i And 1 = 0 Then
                l.Add((i * i) - 1)
            Else
                l.Add((i * i) + 1)
            End If
        Else
            If i And 1 = 0 Then
                l.Add((i * i) + 1)
            Else
                l.Add((i * i) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(","c, l.ToArray))

    watch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

It currently runs 100 iterations of i in 4.3 milliseconds.
I feel like the nested if statements are the main bottleneck here, but I'm not sure of any way I can change them.

So, can this code be made more efficient?

Thanks... :)

Comment: Why is the console.write in the metric? Wouldn't the string.join be in better/faster with a string builder, that you dump at the end?

Comment: You are measuring the speed of Console.WriteLine().  Yes, it is slow.  Not an issue, it only has to be as fast as a human can read.

Comment: Just pasting your code into my default new console project, with Option Strict On, highlights many issues in your code. You need to ensure the code is doing what you want before attempting to optimise it!

Answer (score 1):

First off, pull the `If l.Capacity And 1 <> 0` out of the loop, since it’s always going to be the same.

Then, drop the bit operations in favour of more readable `i Mod 2 = 0` tests: you seem to think that this is more efficient, but in reality such trivial optimisations are best left to the compiler and runtime, they have no place in your code and I seriously doubt that they have *any* measurable impact.

If this is still to inefficient, don’t use an initial capacity and `Add`. Instead, use `Resize` and indexed access to the elements. Then you can also get rid of the other `If` statements by using two loops: one for the even elements and one for the odd elements.

That said, **the `Join` operation is probably by far the slowest step** here (apart from the actual printing to the console, maybe) and **there’s nothing you can do to optimise that.**

Finally, I find the `CType` horribly unreadable: what you’re doing here isn’t a cast – it’s a *parsing operation*. Why not write it as one? `ULong.Parse(…)`. Also, why are you using the unwieldy `My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item` instead of accepting the command line arguments as a parameter to `Main`?

Answer (score 0):

Once I only correct your errors, as I think you intended, I get this output when using Ctrl+F5 with Visual Studio 2010 with a Release build:

> 0,5,8,17,24,37,48,65,80,101,120,145,168,197,224,257,288,325,360,401,440,485,528,577,624,677,728,785,840,901,960,1025,1088,1157,1224,1297,1368,1445,1520,1601,1680,1765,1848,1937,2024,2117,2208,2305,2400,2501,2600,2705,2808,2917,3024,3137,3248,3365,3480,3601,3720,3845,3968,4097,4224,4357,4488,4625,4760,4901,5040,5185,5328,5477,5624,5777,5928,6085,6240,6401,6560,6725,6888,7057,7224,7397,7568,7745,7920,8101,8280,8465,8648,8837,9024,9217,9408,9605,9800,10001
>   33.9106

That's with this code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    Dim l As New List(Of ULong)(CInt(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)))

    For i As ULong = 1 To CULng(l.Capacity)
        ' ONE LINE IF STMT: If l.Capacity And 1 <> 0 Then If i And 1 = 0 Then l.Add((i * i) - 1) Else l.Add((i * i) + 1) Else If i And 1 = 0 Then l.Add((i * i) + 1) Else l.Add((i * i) - 1)
        If (l.Capacity And 1) <> 0 Then
            If (i And 1UL) = 0UL Then
                l.Add((i * i) - 1UL)
            Else
                l.Add((i * i) + 1UL)
            End If
        Else
            If (i And 1UL) = 0UL Then
                l.Add((i * i) + 1UL)
            Else
                l.Add((i * i) - 1UL)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(","c, l.ToArray))

    watch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Using LINQ:

> 0,5,8,17,24,37,48,65,80,101,120,145,168,197,224,257,288,325,360,401,440,485,528,577,624,677,728,785,840,901,960,1025,1088,1157,1224,1297,1368,1445,1520,1601,1680,1765,1848,1937,2024,2117,2208,2305,2400,2501,2600,2705,2808,2917,3024,3137,3248,3365,3480,3601,3720,3845,3968,4097,4224,4357,4488,4625,4760,4901,5040,5185,5328,5477,5624,5777,5928,6085,6240,6401,6560,6725,6888,7057,7224,7397,7568,7745,7920,8101,8280,8465,8648,8837,9024,9217,9408,9605,9800,10001
>   13.0721

That's with:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    Dim arg = CInt(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(","c, Enumerable.Range(1, arg).Select(
                                  Function(i) ((i * i +
                                               If((arg And 1) <> 0,
                                                   If((i And 1) = 0, -1, 1),
                                                   If((i And 1) = 0, 1, -1))).ToString()))))

    watch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Now optimised:

> 0,5,8,17,24,37,48,65,80,101,120,145,168,197,224,257,288,325,360,401,440,485,528,577,624,677,728,785,840,901,960,1025,1088,1157,1224,1297,1368,1445,1520,1601,1680,1765,1848,1937,2024,2117,2208,2305,2400,2501,2600,2705,2808,2917,3024,3137,3248,3365,3480,3601,3720,3845,3968,4097,4224,4357,4488,4625,4760,4901,5040,5185,5328,5477,5624,5777,5928,6085,6240,6401,6560,6725,6888,7057,7224,7397,7568,7745,7920,8101,8280,8465,8648,8837,9024,9217,9408,9605,9800,10001
>   12.5956

And at this point I thought I clearly hit the `Console.WriteLine` variance being within the timing, but even with the code below I still get 12 to 15 milliseconds...

```
Sub Main()
    Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    Dim arg = CInt(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0))

    Dim fn As Func(Of Integer, String) = If((arg And 1) <> 0,
                                            Function(i As Integer) ((i * i + If((i And 1) = 0, -1, 1)).ToString()),
                                            Function(i As Integer) ((i * i + If((i And 1) = 0, 1, -1)).ToString()))

    Dim s = String.Join(","c, Enumerable.Range(1, arg).Select(fn))

    watch.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(s)
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```